# Configuring a repetitive job on aws VS using java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I have to achieve a task, which has 3 steps broadly.

```
1. To run a shell script on AWS ec2 instance , and this script generates output data in a file in s3 bucket
2. Download this output data and process it to generate another set of data
3. Feeding final data to a service.
```

This entire process has to be done with certain time gap, say 5 hrs.

Steps 2,3 are easy to achieve in java using aws java sdk.

I have been trying to do first step too in java program, but so far I have found that this is not that straightforward to do. So another approach I am thinking over is to configure a job on aws itself which runs the shell script after every 5 hours, and when completed my java service would be notified to execute next 2 steps.

But I am not that well versed with AWS, and am not able to decide if it would be a good and doable approach.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a script - that is a bit confusing. How are you communicating with S3 from a script? Are you using the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

All steps above can be performed using the AWS SDK and Lambda.  That way - you can use the AWS SDK for Java in your Lambda function and easily invoke Amazon S3 operations from your Lambda function. Then you can use a cron expression to fire off the Lambda function on a regular schedule.

I would take a step further and use AWS Step functions to build a workflow.